# Sitcone in c# could not be found in etc

Tags: c#, reference, namespaces, global, .net-assembly

i get sitcon cant be foundt

Warning MSB3245 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Siticone.UI". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

and

Error CS0400 The type or namespace name 'Siticone' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

my code is here

````
{
    // Token: 0x02000002 RID: 2
    public partial class Register : global::System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        // Token: 0x06000011 RID: 17 RVA: 0x0000215C File Offset: 0x0000035C
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            bool flag = disposing && this.components != null;
            if (flag)
            {
                this.components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        // Token: 0x06000012 RID: 18 RVA: 0x00002194 File Offset: 0x00000394
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.Animation animation2 = new Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.Animation();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Register));
            this.siticoneDragControl1 = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneDragControl(this.components);
            this.siticoneControlBox1 = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneControlBox();
            this.siticoneControlBox2 = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneControlBox();
            this.siticoneTransition1 = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneTransition();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1 = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedButton();
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2 = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedButton();
            this.siticoneImageButton1 = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneImageButton();
            this.email = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedTextBox();
            this.password = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedTextBox();
            this.username = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedTextBox();
            this.license = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedTextBox();
            this.siticoneShadowForm = new Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneShadowForm(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // siticoneDragControl1
            // 
            this.siticoneDragControl1.TargetControl = this;
            // 
            // siticoneControlBox1
            // 
            this.siticoneControlBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.siticoneControlBox1.BorderRadius = 10;
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this.siticoneControlBox1, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.None);
            this.siticoneControlBox1.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(39)))), ((int)(((byte)(42)))));
            this.siticoneControlBox1.HoveredState.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(232)))), ((int)(((byte)(17)))), ((int)(((byte)(35)))));
            this.siticoneControlBox1.HoveredState.IconColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.siticoneControlBox1.HoveredState.Parent = this.siticoneControlBox1;
            this.siticoneControlBox1.IconColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.siticoneControlBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(367, 5);
            this.siticoneControlBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.siticoneControlBox1.Name = "siticoneControlBox1";
            this.siticoneControlBox1.ShadowDecoration.Parent = this.siticoneControlBox1;
            this.siticoneControlBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 36);
            this.siticoneControlBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.siticoneControlBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.siticoneControlBox1_Click);
            // 
            // siticoneControlBox2
            // 
            this.siticoneControlBox2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.siticoneControlBox2.BorderRadius = 10;
            this.siticoneControlBox2.ControlBoxType = Siticone.UI.WinForms.Enums.ControlBoxType.MinimizeBox;
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this.siticoneControlBox2, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.None);
            this.siticoneControlBox2.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(39)))), ((int)(((byte)(42)))));
            this.siticoneControlBox2.HoveredState.Parent = this.siticoneControlBox2;
            this.siticoneControlBox2.IconColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.siticoneControlBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(306, 5);
            this.siticoneControlBox2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.siticoneControlBox2.Name = "siticoneControlBox2";
            this.siticoneControlBox2.ShadowDecoration.Parent = this.siticoneControlBox2;
            this.siticoneControlBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 36);
            this.siticoneControlBox2.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // siticoneTransition1
            // 
            this.siticoneTransition1.AnimationType = Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.AnimationType.Rotate;
            this.siticoneTransition1.Cursor = null;
            animation2.AnimateOnlyDifferences = true;
            animation2.BlindCoeff = ((System.Drawing.PointF)(resources.GetObject("animation2.BlindCoeff")));
            animation2.LeafCoeff = 0F;
            animation2.MaxTime = 1F;
            animation2.MinTime = 0F;
            animation2.MosaicCoeff = ((System.Drawing.PointF)(resources.GetObject("animation2.MosaicCoeff")));
            animation2.MosaicShift = ((System.Drawing.PointF)(resources.GetObject("animation2.MosaicShift")));
            animation2.MosaicSize = 0;
            animation2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(50);
            animation2.RotateCoeff = 1F;
            animation2.RotateLimit = 0F;
            animation2.ScaleCoeff = ((System.Drawing.PointF)(resources.GetObject("animation2.ScaleCoeff")));
            animation2.SlideCoeff = ((System.Drawing.PointF)(resources.GetObject("animation2.SlideCoeff")));
            animation2.TimeCoeff = 0F;
            animation2.TransparencyCoeff = 1F;
            this.siticoneTransition1.DefaultAnimation = animation2;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this.label1, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.None);
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Light", 10F);
            this.label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-1, 167);
            this.label1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 0, 4, 0);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 23);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 22;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this.label2, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.None);
            this.label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 10.2F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 23);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 27;
            this.label2.Text = "Auth.GG | Register";
            // 
            // siticoneRoundedButton1
            // 
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.BorderThickness = 1;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.CheckedState.Parent = this.siticoneRoundedButton1;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.CustomImages.Parent = this.siticoneRoundedButton1;
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this.siticoneRoundedButton1, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.None);
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(7)))), ((int)(((byte)(127)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))));
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.HoveredState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(213)))), ((int)(((byte)(218)))), ((int)(((byte)(223)))));
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.HoveredState.Parent = this.siticoneRoundedButton1;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(46, 349);
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.Name = "siticoneRoundedButton1";
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.ShadowDecoration.Parent = this.siticoneRoundedButton1;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(340, 33);
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.TabIndex = 26;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.Text = "Back to Login";
            this.siticoneRoundedButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.siticoneRoundedButton1_Click);
            // 
            // siticoneRoundedButton2
            // 
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.BorderThickness = 1;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.CheckedState.Parent = this.siticoneRoundedButton2;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.CustomImages.Parent = this.siticoneRoundedButton2;
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this.siticoneRoundedButton2, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.None);
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(7)))), ((int)(((byte)(127)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))));
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.HoveredState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(213)))), ((int)(((byte)(218)))), ((int)(((byte)(223)))));
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.HoveredState.Parent = this.siticoneRoundedButton2;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(46, 308);
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.Name = "siticoneRoundedButton2";
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.ShadowDecoration.Parent = this.siticoneRoundedButton2;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(340, 33);
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.TabIndex = 28;
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.Text = "Register";
            this.siticoneRoundedButton2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.siticoneRoundedButton2_Click);
            // 
            // siticoneImageButton1
            // 
            this.siticoneImageButton1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.siticoneImageButton1.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
            this.siticoneImageButton1.CheckedState.Parent = this.siticoneImageButton1;
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this.siticoneImageButton1, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.None);
            this.siticoneImageButton1.HoveredState.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
            this.siticoneImageButton1.HoveredState.Parent = this.siticoneImageButton1;
            this.siticoneImageButton1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("siticoneImageButton1.Image")));
            this.siticoneImageButton1.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
            this.siticoneImageButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 43);
            this.siticoneImageButton1.Name = "siticoneImageButton1";
            this.siticoneImageButton1.PressedState.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
            this.siticoneImageButton1.PressedState.Parent = this.siticoneImageButton1;
            this.siticoneImageButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(406, 66);
            this.siticoneImageButton1.TabIndex = 33;
            // 
            // email
            // 
            this.email.AllowDrop = true;
            this.email.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(7)))), ((int)(((byte)(127)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))));
            this.email.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.IBeam;
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this.email, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.None);
            this.email.DefaultText = "Email";
            this.email.DisabledState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(208)))), ((int)(((byte)(208)))), ((int)(((byte)(208)))));
            this.email.DisabledState.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(226)))), ((int)(((byte)(226)))), ((int)(((byte)(226)))));
            this.email.DisabledState.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))));
            this.email.DisabledState.Parent = this.email;
            this.email.DisabledState.PlaceholderForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))));
            this.email.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(39)))), ((int)(((byte)(42)))));
            this.email.FocusedState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(94)))), ((int)(((byte)(148)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.email.FocusedState.Parent = this.email;
            this.email.HoveredState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(94)))), ((int)(((byte)(148)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.email.HoveredState.Parent = this.email;
            this.email.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(56, 206);
            this.email.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.email.Name = "email";
            this.email.PasswordChar = '\0';
            this.email.PlaceholderText = "";
            this.email.SelectedText = "";
            this.email.ShadowDecoration.Parent = this.email;
            this.email.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(315, 37);
            this.email.TabIndex = 34;
            this.email.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            // 
            // password
            // 
            this.password.AllowDrop = true;
            this.password.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(7)))), ((int)(((byte)(127)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))));
            this.password.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.IBeam;
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this.password, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.None);
            this.password.DefaultText = "Password";
            this.password.DisabledState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(208)))), ((int)(((byte)(208)))), ((int)(((byte)(208)))));
            this.password.DisabledState.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(226)))), ((int)(((byte)(226)))), ((int)(((byte)(226)))));
            this.password.DisabledState.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))));
            this.password.DisabledState.Parent = this.password;
            this.password.DisabledState.PlaceholderForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))));
            this.password.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(39)))), ((int)(((byte)(42)))));
            this.password.FocusedState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(94)))), ((int)(((byte)(148)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.password.FocusedState.Parent = this.password;
            this.password.HoveredState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(94)))), ((int)(((byte)(148)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.password.HoveredState.Parent = this.password;
            this.password.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(56, 162);
            this.password.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.password.Name = "password";
            this.password.PasswordChar = '\0';
            this.password.PlaceholderText = "";
            this.password.SelectedText = "";
            this.password.ShadowDecoration.Parent = this.password;
            this.password.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(315, 37);
            this.password.TabIndex = 35;
            this.password.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            // 
            // username
            // 
            this.username.AllowDrop = true;
            this.username.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(7)))), ((int)(((byte)(127)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))));
            this.username.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.IBeam;
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this.username, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.None);
            this.username.DefaultText = "Username";
            this.username.DisabledState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(208)))), ((int)(((byte)(208)))), ((int)(((byte)(208)))));
            this.username.DisabledState.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(226)))), ((int)(((byte)(226)))), ((int)(((byte)(226)))));
            this.username.DisabledState.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))));
            this.username.DisabledState.Parent = this.username;
            this.username.DisabledState.PlaceholderForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))));
            this.username.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(39)))), ((int)(((byte)(42)))));
            this.username.FocusedState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(94)))), ((int)(((byte)(148)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.username.FocusedState.Parent = this.username;
            this.username.HoveredState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(94)))), ((int)(((byte)(148)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.username.HoveredState.Parent = this.username;
            this.username.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(56, 116);
            this.username.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.username.Name = "username";
            this.username.PasswordChar = '\0';
            this.username.PlaceholderText = "";
            this.username.SelectedText = "";
            this.username.ShadowDecoration.Parent = this.username;
            this.username.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(315, 37);
            this.username.TabIndex = 36;
            this.username.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            // 
            // license
            // 
            this.license.AllowDrop = true;
            this.license.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(7)))), ((int)(((byte)(127)))), ((int)(((byte)(243)))));
            this.license.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.IBeam;
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this.license, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.None);
            this.license.DefaultText = "License";
            this.license.DisabledState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(208)))), ((int)(((byte)(208)))), ((int)(((byte)(208)))));
            this.license.DisabledState.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(226)))), ((int)(((byte)(226)))), ((int)(((byte)(226)))));
            this.license.DisabledState.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))));
            this.license.DisabledState.Parent = this.license;
            this.license.DisabledState.PlaceholderForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))));
            this.license.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(39)))), ((int)(((byte)(42)))));
            this.license.FocusedState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(94)))), ((int)(((byte)(148)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.license.FocusedState.Parent = this.license;
            this.license.HoveredState.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(94)))), ((int)(((byte)(148)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.license.HoveredState.Parent = this.license;
            this.license.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(56, 253);
            this.license.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.license.Name = "license";
            this.license.PasswordChar = '\0';
            this.license.PlaceholderText = "";
            this.license.SelectedText = "";
            this.license.ShadowDecoration.Parent = this.license;
            this.license.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(315, 37);
            this.license.TabIndex = 37;
            this.license.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            // 
            // Register
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.Disable;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(35)))), ((int)(((byte)(39)))), ((int)(((byte)(42)))));
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(432, 395);
            this.Controls.Add(this.license);
            this.Controls.Add(this.username);
            this.Controls.Add(this.password);
            this.Controls.Add(this.email);
            this.Controls.Add(this.siticoneImageButton1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.siticoneRoundedButton2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.siticoneRoundedButton1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.siticoneControlBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.siticoneControlBox1);
            this.siticoneTransition1.SetDecoration(this, Siticone.UI.AnimatorNS.DecorationType.BottomMirror);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.Name = "Register";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Auth.GG WInform";
            this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        // Token: 0x04000001 RID: 1
        private global::System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        // Token: 0x04000002 RID: 2
        private global::Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneDragControl siticoneDragControl1;

        // Token: 0x04000004 RID: 4
        private global::Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneControlBox siticoneControlBox1;

        // Token: 0x04000005 RID: 5
        private global::Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneControlBox siticoneControlBox2;

        // Token: 0x04000009 RID: 9
        private global::Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneTransition siticoneTransition1;

        // Token: 0x0400000A RID: 10
        private global::System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedButton siticoneRoundedButton1;
        private Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneShadowForm siticoneShadowForm;
        private Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedButton siticoneRoundedButton2;
        private Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneImageButton siticoneImageButton1;
        private Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedTextBox license;
        private Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedTextBox username;
        private Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedTextBox password;
        private Siticone.UI.WinForms.SiticoneRoundedTextBox email;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Siticone Library is present in your project (in bin folder) and the library is referenced "using Siticone..."

There is a newer version Siticone.Desktop.UI 2.0.04, use that one.